# How to set HTML encoding in HTMLLayout in logback?

Tags: java, logging, logback

By default logback only produces the following header for HTML log files:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Logback Log Messages</title>
<style  type="text/css">

</style>
</head>
```

But encoding here is not set. And some browsers default encoding to something they want like 'windows-1251' or 'ISO-8859-1' or 'ISO-8859-5'.

How do I add something like

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-16">
```

to HTML header? Also since all strings in Java are UTF-16, shouldn't this be permanently set in logback source code?

Is there any way to do it via logback configuration file or should I create my own HTMLLayout descendant?

Comment: Do not confuse the internal representation of Java strings with UTF-8 encoding of Unicode characters.

Comment: @Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen Aren't Java strings in UTF-16?

Comment: you are right:  http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/core/basic/intl/faq.jsp#text-representation

Comment: @Thorbjørn but logback log file doesn't seem to be UTF-16. More like UTF-8 because ASCII symbols are represented by a single byte there as I understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears from the javadocs that no such option exists, but check the source to be certain.  Logback is still a moving target until 1.0.

If you find it is not present, then raise a bug in the logback JIRA instance -- http://jira.qos.ch/secure/Dashboard.jspa - and ask for it, or submit a patch that adds the functionality.

Answer (score 1):

You couldn't set "head" tag,but you can extend "HTMLLayout",such example:

```java
public class CustomizationHTMLLayout extends HTMLLayoutBase<ILoggingEvent>{

    @Override
    public String getFileHeader()
    {
        StringBuilder sbuf = new StringBuilder();
        sbuf.append("<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN\"");
        sbuf.append(" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd\">");
        sbuf.append(LINE_SEPARATOR);
        sbuf.append("<html>");
        sbuf.append(LINE_SEPARATOR);
        sbuf.append("  <head>");
        sbuf.append(LINE_SEPARATOR);
        // customization code
        sbuf.append("    <meta charset=\"utf-8\">");
        sbuf.append(LINE_SEPARATOR);
        // customization code
        sbuf.append("    <meta http-equiv=\"content-type\" content=\"text/html; charset=utf-8\">");
        sbuf.append(LINE_SEPARATOR);
        sbuf.append("    <title>");
        sbuf.append(title);
        sbuf.append("</title>");
        sbuf.append(LINE_SEPARATOR);

        cssBuilder.addCss(sbuf);

        sbuf.append(LINE_SEPARATOR);
        sbuf.append("  </head>");
        sbuf.append(LINE_SEPARATOR);
        sbuf.append("<body>");
        sbuf.append(LINE_SEPARATOR);

        return sbuf.toString();
    }

}
```

if you use xml configraution , change "layout" tag,use your class

```xml
<layout class="CustomizationHTMLLayout">
```